# TFS Continuous Integration

Tags: tfs

I have a solution checked in to a TFS branch. That solution includes a project located in another TFS branch. Our sys admin creates a build definition so that each time we check code in. An automated build is triggered. The automated build is failing because it doesn’t see the project file of the project located in another branch. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you said, the reason is that "`it doesn’t see the project file of the project located in another branch`."

During the build, the first step is **getting the sources** from repository. If missing the needed files for the solution during getting sources, the build will be failed.

In your case, you need to include `another branch` (which the project located in) in **Repository Mappings**, means that you need to **also** get the needed sources from  `another branch`.

Actually, the best way to fix that is adding the project to the solution in the same branch.

[image]